# Opening a Specific Email in GMail Using C# and WatiN

Tags: c#, watin

I've been working with sending and receiving email through various web-mail clients using WatiN, I've got logging in, writing and sending emails working perfectly, however I am having issues opening specific emails.

Each email I send has a specific id codein the subject, but I can't work out how to tell WatiN to actually click the specific email.  I would of thought it would be something like:

```
ie.Link(Find.ByText("UN1QU3_1D")).Click();
```

But due to how Gmail and Live set up their display this doesn't seem to work...

Also, a slightly simpler question, is there a way of preventing WatiN closing the browser once it has finished with it?

Does anyone have any bright ideas?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since all gmail message titles are actually in spans not links, I think this will work:

```
ie.Span(Find.ByText("UN1QU3_1D")).Click();
```

Also, as far as I remember, WatiN won't close a browser unless you specifically closed them, like:

```
ie.Close();
```

**UPDATE:**

Finally it worked for me :D Span ieFramesSpan = ie.Frames[3].Span( delegate(Span s) { return s.InnerHtml==null? false: s.InnerHtml.Contains("UN1QU3_1D"); }); ieFramesSpan.MouseDown();

Comment: You still might want to check you browser AutoClose property
 ie.AutoClose

Comment: Hi Shady,
Many thanks for the prompt, I receive the error "...Could not find SPAN element tag matching criteria: Attribute 'inntertext' matches '^ *UN1QU3_1D *$'..." Any other thoughts?

Comment: Finally it worked for me :D

Span ieFramesSpan = 
ie.Frames[3].Span(
  delegate(Span s)
  { 
    return s.InnerHtml==null? false: s.InnerHtml.Contains("UN1QU3_1D"); 
    });
ieFramesSpan.MouseDown();

Comment: Quick addition Shady; Not sure if you have used the screen shot function or not, however if you screen shot it should save the whole page, however within Gmail it only grabs what is visible in the window rather than scrolling to view the whole page. Any thoughts?

Comment: Never tried it before.. & even when I tried it now it seems to have something going wrong on my machine.. I get a black pic!!

Comment: Fair enough. Thanks for the help!